# Why am I getting "prompt is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am learning JavaScript and downloaded WebStorm. I made some basic code but I can't get it to work. I keep getting "prompt is not defined."

I've enabled browser under JSHint, and also used `window.prompt` (this just gave "window is not defined").

```
let radius = prompt("Enter radius")
let height = prompt("Enter height")
```

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: It seems like you're running this in node. Run it in a browser

Comment: @zerkms i just press run within the webstorm ui

Comment: @weegee Yea, i know, that one didnt help me tho

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze How do i do that

Comment: @OwenLiu When you run it in webstorm, it will run it as a JavaScript file. `prompt` is an object provided by the browser like Chrome or Firefox. Obviously Webstorm is not a browser, so it is undefined.

Comment: To do it, add it in a index.html and open it in the browser. Or open chrome and paste it in the Developer Console

Comment: @MauriceNino oh i see thanks

Comment: The global object `window` is not a JavaScript built-in. It is provided by the browser, as explained by @MauriceNino. If you run the code in another environment and not in a browser, it is very likely this global object won't be available. Calling the method `prompt` in the global scope is the same as `window.prompt` when executed in a browser.